unstable reading on /dev/ttyS1 openwrt
I am trying to read rs485 messages (raw hex data, no \n \r what ever, 1 message/sec is sent by device).
cat /dev/rs485 works on the morning, but not on the afternoon (siesta?).
Are shell commands reliable?
I use default stty configuration.
How can it be so unstable?
Thank you in advance for your ideas!

PS: why "Hello!" never appears on top of my messages?
